# Add unique key of my own to slack event requests

Tags: slack, slack-api

I created a slack app with distribution (multiple clients)
and I subscribe to events several events like a message posted in a channel.

Beside the `team_id` [field](https://api.slack.com/events-api) for identifying the client team - is there an ability to put my own key for a client?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Sack does not store any custom data for you. Its your job as an app developer to store all team related information for your app and link it to the Slack `team_id`. This is usually done with a database.

You can however include custom IDs with Slack requests, e.g. in the response you get from an interactive message. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971885/4379151) for more details on how this works.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand your answer right in the other thread - it still doesn't allow me to add some values/field/tokens to the incoming events, right? Only request&response in interactive messages.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can of course add some GET parameters in the event URL, but those would be constant for your app, which I understand is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for unique parameter per client (workspace/team).
But - where can I find the option to add some GET parameters to the event URL?

Comment: Simply by adding them the the Request URL you configure for your app under "Event Subscription". e.g. `https://www.example.com/app/event.php?key1=value1;key2=value2`
But as I said those would be constant for you app and all teams, so it does not really solve your problem as I understand.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It does not solve my problem.
Thank you for your reply's.