# How to pass a value from slack channel to `Options Load URL` in Slack App

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, slack, slack-api

I have a slack app implemented in node.js where I am dynamically displaying a drop-down menu from an `Options Load URL` to a channel on the Slack group.

The drop down is getting displayed correctly based on the options JSON that I am returning form the external URL,

but now the problem is that I need to have separate items in the drop-down menu based on what the user has entered on the slack channel.

For example:

If the user says: `give me choices for option 1`: then the value `1` should be passed to the `Options Load URL` and the code that I have implemented at that URL will reply with the appropriate JSON based on the input value `1`.

Next, when the User says `give me choices for option 2`: then the value `2` should be passed to the `Options Load URL` and the code implemented there will reply the options based on the value `2` that it receives.

The code at the `Options Load URL` is already implemented. The code for extracting the number `1` or `2` from the user message is also implemented.

The values `1` or `2` ... etc. are not constant or fixed. These can by random and the API at `Options Load URL` will be able to correctly handle these values.

I just need to figure out a way to send these values to the `Options Load URL` somehow.

Is it possible to do this somehow in Slack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `name` property in your request to pass a custom value to the part of your app that handles the options requests from Slack ("Options Load URL"). I use it usually to select which predefined options list to return, but you can also use it to dynamically create a new option list based on the value.

For reference here is the example Slack request for creating a dynamic menu (from the [offical documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-menus#menu_dynamic)), where you can see the name property under action. In this example it has the value `"bugs_list"`:

```
{
    "text": "What's bugging you?",
    "response_type": "in_channel",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Upgrade your Slack client to use messages like these.",
            "color": "3AA3E3",
            "attachment_type": "default",
            "callback_id": "select_remote_1234",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "bugs_list",
                    "text": "Which random bug do you want to resolve?",
                    "type": "select",
                    "data_source": "external",
                    "min_query_length": 3,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is what your Options Load URL will receive. Notice the `name` parameter.

```
{
    "name": "bugs_list",
    "value": "bot",
    "callback_id": "select_remote_1234",
    "team": {
        "id": "T012AB0A1",
        "domain": "pocket-calculator"
    },
    "channel": {
        "id": "C012AB3CD",
        "name": "general"
    },
    "user": {
        "id": "U012A1BCJ",
        "name": "bugcatcher"
    },
    "action_ts": "1481670445.010908",
    "message_ts": "1481670439.000007",
    "attachment_id": "1",
    "token": "verification_token_string"
}
```

The `name` parameter is a common parameter in a HTTP request, so you can put pretty much everything in there, even data structures, as long as they are encoded as strings. Also see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969047/can-i-send-custom-properties-data-in-slack-message-attachments/45971885#45971885) that talks about the limits of passing data in Slack parameters.

Comment: Thanks, This is kind of what I ended up doing. But in my case things were a bit more complicated as I was using this name value later when I got the response back through the actions to determine what kind of action the User had performed. (I also had Button Clicks which I differentiated using this name to figure out which button the user had clicked.) So, I ended up appending my value to the name as a space separated string. This didn't seem like an elegant solution, but it works for now.

Comment: cool. I do the same, but usually use JSON encoding for my data structure. I agree that is does not appear like an elegant solution, but there not any good alternatives.