# updating/dismissing message after dialog submitted

Tags: slack-api

Is there a way to do any of the following:

a.  Update a chat message that initiated a dialog.
b.  Store "hidden" fields in a dialog.

Basically, I have a bot message that opens from a button on a message attachment.  I know when the user clicks the button, I get the ts of the message and at that time I could alter it.  However, the workflow is not complete until the user has submitted the dialog, but the submit on the dialog loses all the original_message stuff and the ts of the dialog being submitted no longer corresponds with the original, calling message.

If there was a mechanism to store hiddens, I could stash the original ts or the response url on the form itself.

Thanks!  This is my first slack workflow, so any advise is appreciated as usual!

.....

*The suggested [duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969047/can-i-send-custom-properties-data-in-slack-message-attachments) refers to an interactive message, which I'm using to call the dialog already.*

*However, that isn't where my problem is, it is the dialog submission.*

*You don't have any access to the button elements on a dialog and the dialog element can only have 5 elements of type: text, select, text area.  Plus it's a bit overkill considering that a action invocation from an interactive message actually includes the original message in the post back to your server.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i send custom properties/data in slack message attachments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969047/can-i-send-custom-properties-data-in-slack-message-attachments)

Comment: Sure I can take a look.

Comment: dialogs and interactive messages aren't the same thing, I launch the dialog from a interactive message and I'm trying to get a reference back to said message from the submit on the dialog.  so this is not a duplicate, but in fact a great question :D.  i put this into slack dev support and got a response, it's a bit hacky, but  i'll post it once i get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So slack dev support got back to me:

> Thanks for writing in, this is a great question!
>
> You can use the callback_id parameter when calling dialog.open to store a string that will help your app locate the message. This callback_id will be returned to you in the dialog submission.
>
> In your case, you could store the original message's ts and channel_id so that > you can locate the message to update.
>
> I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions!

So, it's a bit hacky (imo), but i did get it to work so I thought I'd close this question in case anyone else ran into this.

I'm just parsing the original ts value inside the callback w/ some other data i can use when the form submits.  The only limitation to this is that it only stores 200 characters but that should be sufficient considering that is in addition to the 5 fields you have on the dialog and the other stuff slack gives you in the post (user, channel, etc).

Comment: Could you explain how to get the message payload from just a message_ts?