# Can Hubot Slack bot store sessions

Tags: django, slack-api, hubot

I am trying to implement simple slack bot. So I have configured `hubot` which will take inputs from `slack` and passing it to my webapp (`django app`) and it will take whatever the response from `django-app` and will reply to slack.

In this process I am trying to store session in `django` using `request.session` but that is not reflected in `slack`. If I am accessing the `django-url` in browser it is able to store sessions and getting proper response with session.

So does the problem lie with `slack` or my approach and is there a way to store sessions in hubot when requesting to `django-app` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not speak to the specific technologies you use (hubot, django), but I am using server sessions with my Slack apps all the time and can give you a general answer on how it works. Note that my Slack apps are build with PHP, but I think its safe to assume that the principles are the same.

**Slack does not support sessions**

In general Slack does not support sessions or context. Instead everything is request based. So if you want to have sessions to keep a functional context between requests you need to organize that by yourself in your Slack app.

**Challenge for using server sessions with server requests**

One challenge is that most server sessions are designed to work with a client that uses a browser. e.g. a PHP server session will store a cookie in the browser, so the server knows, which requests belong to the same session. This does obviously not work with Slack, since all Slack requests are coming from a server and and there is no browser involved.

**Approach for using server sessions with Slack**

But you can use severs session with Slack with these two tricks:

*Manually set the session ID*

Usually the ID of a session is chosen automatically by the server, but you can also set it manually. This allows you to tell the server to continue an existing session that was started with a previous request.

*Include session ID in Slack control*

The functional session of a user is tied together by the Slack controls he uses. (e.g. an interactive button). Its possible to include custom data in those controls (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971885/4379151) for details) and that allows you to include the current session ID in it.

*Full approach*

You include the ID of your current session in the Slack controls, that you create with your app (e.g. an interactive button). Once the user clicks a button Slack will send a request to your app, which will include the session ID. That allows your app to continue an already started server session.