# How to determine which question was prompted to the user with interactive messages?

Tags: slack-api

I tried running one of the demos using slacks apis, specifically for interactive messages.

I want to do the following:

1. ask the user question 1
2. ask the user question 2
3. ask the user question 3

What I don't understand is how do I know when the user is responding to a particular question?

Say in my database I have a questions table, where I store question #1, #2 and #3 etc.

When I get a response from a user, depending on the question_id I will then trigger the next question.

How do I know exactly which question the interactive message originated from?  is there a way for me to get the question_id in the payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach to determine which of your interactive messages the user answered is to use `callback_id`. You can specify it for each each attachment containing an interactive message (a set of buttons, a menu, etc.) and it will be included in the response request to your app.

Here is what the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/interactive-message-field-guide#attachment_fields) says about the `callback_id`:

> The provided string will act as a unique identifier for the collection
>   of buttons within the attachment. It will be sent back to your message
>   button action URL with each invoked action. This field is required
>   when the attachment contains message buttons. It is key to identifying
>   the interaction you're working with.

If you have multiple buttons each will have its own name, which you can use to identify which button was clicked (in combination with the `callback_id`).

If you need to store more data you can use [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969047/can-i-send-custom-properties-data-in-slack-message-attachments/45971885#45971885). With that you could store your `question_id` directly in the `value` property of a button (e.g. as JSON string).

Comment: do u make slack apps?

Comment: I do. Got 3 apps in the App Directory. My newest is Easy Poll.